# How do I clear my input that has value in it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have an input that's populated with values returned from an API that's stored into Redux state:

```
state = {
  popoverScenarioName: null,
}

scenarioNameChange = (e) => (
  this.setState({popoverScenarioName: e.target.value})
)

// ....

<StyledInput
  placeholder="Scenario Name"
  onChange={(e) => scenarioNameChange(e)}
  onFocus={(e) => e.target.select()}
  value={this.state.scenarioName || database.inputs.scenarioName}
/>
```

When I click into the input and hit backspace to clear the entire field, it always repopulates the value with `database.inputs.scenarioName`.

I've tried setting state to something like

```
state = {
  popoverScenarioName: null || this.props.database.inputs.scenarioName,
}
```

but that didn't seem to work neither. My other guess would be to write a dispatch to change `database.inputs.scenarioName` directly?

Comment: Please post the `scenarioNameChange` part of the code in your question too.

Comment: @DaveNewton I mentioned in the question that this value is from an API that's loaded into Redux state.

Comment: Okay, `this.state.scenarioName` will always be falsey, since it doesn't exist, so it'll always be replaced with `database.inputs.scenarioName`. What do you *want* it to do?

Comment: To expand on what Dave is saying, `value` should probably be `value={this.state. popoverScenarioName || database.inputs.scenarioName}` instead of the way you wrote it: `value={this.state.scenarioName || database.inputs.scenarioName}`

Comment: Not sure what you'd like to do but I think you want to modify the state in Redux and not in component state. Is something like in the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/j44pn2joo9) working for you? If that's going into the right direction I could write an answer with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it with this prop:

```
scenarioName={this.state.popoverScenarioName === null ? database.inputs.scenarioName : this.state.popoverScenarioName}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
state = {
   popoverScenarioName: null,
}

scenarioNameChange = (e) => (
   this.setState({popoverScenarioName: e.target.value})
 )

 clickHandler = () => {
    //...doing something here
    setState({popoverScenarioName: null})
 }

<StyledInput
  placeholder="Scenario Name"
  onChange={(e) => scenarioNameChange(e)}
  onFocus={(e) => e.target.select()}
  value={this.state.popoverScenarioName}
 />

<button onClick={this.clickHandler}>add todo</button>
```

where is your click handler?
after click clear your form

this one going from redux state "this.props.database."?